# Next.JS Build error: Can't resolve '.../next/dist/client/next.js' In Azure Web Applications

Tags: node.js, next.js, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm tryingto deploy a Next.JS application in a Azure Web App Application, using the Kudu ( App Service Build Service ) synchronized with a Github Repo.

But in the build, throws the above error:

```
5. Build Application

> bdd-viewer@1.0.0 build
> next build

info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/local/Temp/8da0688d45b620b/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'D:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1rnnhmla1-rtm-app-001\Temp\8da0688d45b620b'


> Build failed because of webpack errors
Failed exitCode=1, command="C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\16.13.0\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\npm\8.1.0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" run build
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.\r\nnpm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.\r\n+---------------------------------------------------------+\r\n�  Update available 3.8.1 -> 3.10.0                       �\r\n�  Run the following to update                            �\r\n�    npm i --save-dev prisma@latest                       �\r\n�    npm i @prisma/client@latest                          �\r\n+---------------------------------------------------------+\r\nFailed to compile.\r\n\r\nModule not found: Error: Can't resolve './C:/local/Temp/8da0688d45b620b/node_modules/next/dist/client/next.js' in 'D:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1rnnhmla1-rtm-app-001\Temp\8da0688d45b620b'\r\n\r\n\r\n> Build failed because of webpack errors\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\96.40113.5578\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd deploy.cmd
```

##### Deploy Script

The deploy script is based in [Company Comunicator deploy script](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-apps-company-communicator/blob/master/deploy.app.cmd), and the difference is the Deployment step, that has this code

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

echo 1. KuduSync to DEPLOYMENT_TEMP 
call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

echo 2. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

echo 3. Install npm packages
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! ci --quiet
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd

echo 4. Apply Database Changes
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run prisma db push
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd

echo 5. Build Application
pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! run build
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
popd

echo 6. KuduSync to DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
echo "Syncing site to Deployment Target"
call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -x true -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

I'm using node 16.13.0, and the same error happens in 32 and 64 bits. I tryed to use the next-transpile-modules to, using this config

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['next']);

module.exports = withTM({});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be transpiling `next` with `next-transpile-modules`.